# Input Space Separated Numbers in arrays using getline in cpp

Tags: c++, string, syntax, getline

i have been working on a problem in which i am required to take space separated inputs(<=10) followed by other set of space separated inputs in next line in two separate arrays in CPP.I am using getline function in cpp for this.The problem i am facing is the last line of taking inputs.I can't figure out what problem i am facing.As the last line comes,the output stops and waits for me to type something after which it delivers the output.Here is my code..

```
while(test--)
{

    int len[100];
    int pos[100];


    string a,b,code;
        // int t=1;


    cin>>code;


    cin.ignore();//ignores the next cin and waits till a is not input


    getline(cin,a);


  //  deque<char> code1;

   // code1.assign(code.begin(),code.end());




    int k=0;
    int t=a.length();
    for(int i=0;i<t/2+1;i++)//converts two n length arrays pos[] and len[] 
    {

        scanf("%d",&len[i]);

    while(a[k]==' ')
    {
        k++;

    }




            pos[i]=a[k]-48;
            k++;
               }



        //int c;}
```

`

Comment: Ok!  you're taking space separated inputs. But what you're trying to do after this?. 
Intention is not clear at the moment and code looks a bit vague.

Comment: It looks like he might be new to C++. A lot of things are going wrong here.

Comment: @Geoff_Montee : hmmm. but no worries as we are there to help..

Comment: Yeah. Didn't mean to imply otherwise. It's just looking like his approach is wrong to this program. He might want to read up on C++ IO a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is confusing, and doesn't look like it should work. You are using blocking input with cin/scanf, so it is normal for it to wait for you if there is no input ready on standard input.

This is what it looks like you were trying to do:

- Read in the line into a string called `a` using `getline`.
- Read the data from `a` into your array using `scanf`.

However, `scanf` is not made for this. The `scanf` function gets input from the keyboard. I think you wanted to use [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/) to input the values from the string `a`.

But even better would be to use [stringstreams](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/).

At first I thought that you were trying to read the length of the inputs from the command line, so I suggested this:

```
size_t arr_len;

cin >> arr_len;

if (cin.fail())
{
    cerr << "Input error getting length" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

int* len = new int[arr_len];
int* pos = new int[arr_len];

for (int count = 0; count < arr_len; count++)
{
    cin >> len[count];

    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Input error on value number " << count << " of len" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }        
}


for (int count = 0; count < arr_len; count++)
{
    cin >> pos[count];

    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Input error on value number " << count  << " of pos" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

delete [] pos;
delete [] len;
```

Then I looked more carefully. It looks like this is what you wanted to do. I'm using `std::vector` instead of `int[]`, but if you really want, it isn't hard to change it.

```
string line;

getline(cin, line);

if (cin.fail())
{
    cout << "Failure reading first line" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

istringstream iss;

iss.str(line);

vector<int> len;

size_t elements = 0;

while (!iss.eof())
{
    int num;
    iss >> num;

    elements++;

    if (iss.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Error reading element number " << elements << " in len array" << endl;
    }

    len.push_back(num);
}

getline(cin, line);

if (cin.fail())
{
    cout << "Failure reading second line" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

iss.clear();
iss.str(line);

vector<int> pos;

elements = 0;

while (!iss.eof())
{
    int num;
    iss >> num;

    elements++;

    if (iss.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Error reading element number " << elements << " in pos array" << endl;
    }

    pos.push_back(num);
}
```

Comment: What's with the downvote? I had a hard time figuring out what the OP was trying to do, but still offered some potential solutions based on what he might have wanted to do.